# Что не так с кодом по calc?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Опишите класс Calculator, который будет реализовывать следующие методы и поля:

- `sum(self, a, b)` - сложение чисел a и b
- `sub(self, a, b)` - вычитание
- `mul(self, a, b)` - умножение
- `div(self, a, b, mod=False)` - деление.
  Если параметр `mod == True`, то метод должен возвращать остаток от деления вместо деления. По умолчанию `mod=False`.
- `history(self, n)` - этот метод должен возвращать строку с операцией по ее номеру относительно текущего момента (1 - последняя, 2 - предпоследняя). Формат вывода: `sum(5, 15) == 20` (ОБРАТИТЕ ВНИМАНИЕ: В ВИДЕО ЗАДАНИЕ БЫЛО ОЗВУЧЕНО ПО-ДРУГОМУ! Для прохождения тестов МЕТОД ДОЛЖЕН ВОЗВРАЩАТЬ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, А НЕ ВЫВОДИТЬ ЕГО НА ЭКРАН)
- `last` - строка того же формата, что в предыдущем пункте, в которой содержится информация о последней операции по всем созданным объектам калькулятора. Т.е. это последняя операция последнего использованного объекта калькулятор. Если операций пока не было, то None.
- `clear(cls)` - метод, который очищает last, т.е. присваивает ему значение None.

Формат вывода

При сохранении строк в history и last нужно выводить только один знак после запятой дробного числа. При выполнении деления с mod сам параметр mod не нужно записывать в лог.

Примечания

В конец файла добавьте строки:

```
from classes1_tests import Test

Test(Calculator).run_all()
```

Таким образом, в коде программы должно быть только описание класса и эти две строки.

Программа:

```
class Calculator:
    last = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.history_array = []
   
    def sum(self, a, b):
        self.history_array.append( a + b)
        self.last = self.history_array[-1]
        return a + b
    def sub(self, a, b):
        self.history_array.append( a - b)
        self.last = self.history_array[-1]
        return a - b
    def mul(self, a, b):

        self.history_array.append(a * b)
        self.last = self.history_array[-1]
        return a * b
    def div(self, a, b, mod=False):
        if mod:
            self.history_array.append( a % b)
            self.last = self.history_array[-1]
            return a % b
        else:
            self.history_array.append(a / b)
            self.last = self.history_array[-1]
            return a / b
    def history(self, n):
        try:
            result = self.history_array[-n]
        except IndexError:
            result = None
        return result

    def clear(self): 
        self.last = None


from classes1_tests import Test

Test(Calculator).run_all()
```

Comment: Какие конкретно у вас возникли проблемы с кодом? Вы не реализовали все требуемые методы, и метод getHis() вообще не требовался. Запись операций в историю у вас соответствует заданию, насколько я могу судить.

Answer (score 0):

Вы присваиваете не классовой переменной `last`, а переменной объекта: вам нужно вместо `self.last` писать `Calculator.last`. Вот так должно сработать:

```
class Calculator:
    last = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.history_array = []
   
    def sum(self, a, b):
        self.history_array.append( a + b)
        Calculator.last = self.history_array[-1]
        return a + b

    def sub(self, a, b):
        self.history_array.append( a - b)
        Calculator.last = self.history_array[-1]
        return a - b

    def mul(self, a, b):
        self.history_array.append(a * b)
        Calculator.last = self.history_array[-1]
        return a * b

    def div(self, a, b, mod=False):
        if mod:
            self.history_array.append( a % b)
            Calculator.last = self.history_array[-1]
            return a % b
        else:
            self.history_array.append(a / b)
            Calculator.last = self.history_array[-1]
            return a / b

    def history(self, n):
        try:
            result = self.history_array[-n]
        except IndexError:
            result = None
        return result

    def clear(self): 
        Calculator.last = None


from classes1_tests import Test

Test(Calculator).run_all()
```

Comment: дает ошибку=(((

Comment: @Andrey не принимают код или интерпретатор выдает ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1342384d-2223-48c2-bd14-692f3c264972", line 44, in <module>
    Test(Calculator).run_all()
  File "/temp/executing/classes1_tests.py", line 85, in run_all
    self.test_sum()
  File "/temp/executing/classes1_tests.py", line 13, in test_sum
    assert c.last == "sum(1, 2) == 3", "при сложении не записался last"
AssertionError: при сложении не записался last